# Scalar product in vector/coordinate form

Tags: trigonometry, vector-analysis

As I know, $a*b = |a|*|b|*cos(a,b)$ in vector form

And $a*b = (a_1,a_2)*(b_1,b_2) = a_1*b_1+a_2*b_2$.

1)

$$a*b=?$$

$$a=2i-3j+5k$$

$$b=i+2j+8k$$

SOLUTION: $a*b = (2,-3,5)*(1,2,8) = 2*1+(-3)*2+5*8 = 36.$

I'm unsure about the angle between them? Do I have to do only multiplication of those two?

$$a*b = (2i-3j+5k)*(i+2j+8k) = \dots$$

2)

$$a*b=?$$
$$a=(1,2,3)$$
$$b=(4,5,6)$$

Do I have to do the same?

SOLUTION: $(a*b) = (1,2,3)*(4,5,6) = 1*4+2*5+3*6 = 32$

3) Find the angle between $a$ and $b$?

$$a=2i-j+2k$$
$$b=i+j+k$$

SOLUTION: a*b = (2,-1,2)*(1,1,1) = 3

|a| = 3

|b| = sqrt(3)

cos(a,b)=?

What's the formula for calculating the angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  for 1, you are given the components, so use the formula you have after "And" but with three components and you are there.  Note that $i,j,k$ are unit vectors, so $i\cdot i=j \cdot j = k \cdot k =1$  For 2, the same.  For 3, get the dot product the same way, evaluate $|a|=\sqrt {a \cdot a}$ and $|b|$, then use these to get $\cos (a,b)$ by combining your first two equations.

Comment: I think I got the first two, is that correct? Also, for third one I can't understand what do you mean..

Comment: Yes, you are correct for the first two.  You were not asked for the angle on those.  Now for 3, do the same to get $a \cdot b$ the first way.  Then if you have $|a|$ and $|b|$, you can use the equality after "As I know" to compute $\cos (a,b)$.  Do you know how to find $|a|$?  I gave you that.

Comment: I've done all the calculations (I believe) and now I have to find cos. How is cos determinated?

Comment: Your calculations so far are correct.  Now $\cos (a,b)=\frac {a \cdot b}{|a||b|}$.  You use the $\arccos$ function, which is the inverse function of the cosine.  If $\cos \theta = x, \arccos x = \theta$ (at least in the first quadrant)

Comment: Hm.. I never used that function before, is there any example?

Comment: Ok, I saw your edit and I get cos = (1/sqrt(3)). Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Do you know any angles with that cosine?

Comment: Well, not really. I am having troubles to find some information how to determinate cos and sin of certain values, such as 1/2, 1, 0 etc using a coordinate system.

Comment: Sorry, there is no nice angle there.  I would leave it as $\arccos \frac {\sqrt 3}3$

Comment: Thanks. Is there any link/video or other material you recommend to learn how to determinate the value of cos0, cos1, sin0, sin1, sin(1/2) and other common angles using the coordinate system?

Comment: You can start with the [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).  Things like $\sin 1$ are nothing nice, but some things like $\sin \frac {\pi}3$ are.

Comment: I think I found this http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~loftin/precalcfal05/values.pdf quite interesting! Combined with yours, it will be of great help. Thank you!